# How do I find out what libraries I need to require?

Tags: help, require

When I write elisp, since I already have a lot of packages required which in turn have required other code, I am able to use a lot of functions without requiring them. When I give the code to someone else though, it sometimes fails and tells them some functions don't exist.

My question is, how can I know in some piece of elisp code what I should be requiring explicitly?

I tried just calling `describe-function` on every function I used, but there are certain functions for which it doesn't tell me what I need to require. For example:

`M-x describe-function cl-concatenate`

Gives me:

```
cl-concatenate is a compiled Lisp function.

(cl-concatenate TYPE SEQUENCE...)

Concatenate, into a sequence of type TYPE, the argument SEQUENCEs.
```

With no mention that I need to require `'cl`.

I even tried with a blank Emacs, but it seems that depending on the OS, you might need an explicit require while on others you don't. So when I try with a blank Emacs it still works for me, but not for everyone else.

Comment: You never need to require `cl`. That package is obsolete since Emacs 24.3. You need to require [`cl-lib`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html) instead. (Note that this package ships with Emacs.) If you need cl functions you directly write `(require 'cl-lib)` in your code. If you only need cl macros you can replace it by `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))`.

Comment: `flycheck-mode` uses the Emacs lisp byte compiler to generate a warning about unknown functions at the end of your lisp library. Since flycheck uses a separate Emacs instance with `emacs -Q` and `--batch` for that test it quite reliable detects missing `require` forms. Check for a flycheck-mark on the last word of your lisp file.

Comment: "it seems that depending on the OS, you might need an explicit require while on others you don't" -- example, please?

Comment: "cl-concatenate is an autoloaded Lisp function in ‘cl-extra.el’." *should* be what you are seeing.  Are you by any chance using an OS package of Emacs which fails to include any of the elisp sources?  I believe Debian/Ubuntu is deficient in this way unless you install a separate `emacs-el` OS package.

Comment: @phils In Ubuntu 18.04 there is a package `emacs25-el`. @Didier A. Please, do not misinterpret Phils' comment. Even if `cl-concatenate` is defined in `cl-extra` the promoted way to include all cl functionality is still `(require 'cl-lib)`. `cl-extra` is pulled in on demand via `autoload`.

Comment: @Tobias If I'm using the aliased functions, like concatenate instead of cl-concatenate, I still need to require cl-lib instead of cl ?

Comment: @phils On OpenSuse tumbleweed, I don't need to require cl-lib to use concatenate even when I start with emacs -Q, while on MacOS, a user of my package was getting an error saying there's no concatenate function. Both with Emacs 26.3

Comment: @Tobias Ah, I'll use flycheck-mode then. I just tried it, and it works for most things, but not for cl-lib, it seems with my Emacs I do not need to require cl-lib to use it. Could that be the case?

Comment: @DidierA. I guess there is some `site-lisp` using `(require 'cl)` on one of those systems.

Comment: n.b. `cl` and `cl-lib` are different things.  The latter is the newer library which name-spaces everything.  So `concatenate` comes from `cl`, and `cl-concatenate` comes from `cl-lib`.  Loading `cl-lib` gives you the latter but not the former.  If you use the old names then you need to require `cl`.

Comment: You can additionally use the command `package-lint-package`. This also warns about `cl` problems.